# Is there a good replacement for Growl/Prowl?

Tags: applescript, bash, notifications, growl

I have several remote Raspberry Pies from which I have been sending notices to my Mac and iOS devices using a combination of Growl and Prowl. Growl is no longer supported. Beginning with Catalina, Growl crashed quite often and with Big Sur it is very unstable. I'm looking for a replacement messaging system that I can use with existing bash scripts on the remote Pies.

I can use Prowl's API to send messages to the iOS devices, but not to the Mac. I can use OSASCRIPT via SSH to send messages to the Mac, but they don't make it to the iOS devices. I can use email which gets to all devices, but ends up making a very cluttered inbox. I've looked at Boxcar, but it seems to be a little much for my needs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an app called [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) which has apps for the Mac and iPhone/iPad. It can receive messages of various levels of “urgent-ness” even to the point of being allowed to bypass “Do Not Disturb” on iOS 14 if you so choose.

Pushover has an API that allows you to send messages using `curl` and it is very easy to use, and has very generous usage allowances. Using `curl` also means that it should work from a Raspberry Pi or any other Unix-y system.

The iPhone/iPad app, Android app, and Mac cost $5 each (iPhone and iPad is a single $5 purchase, Android is $5, Mac app is $5). These are one-time purchases, not subscriptions.

This is a service I had used since 2014 and found to be extremely reliable, easy to use, and inexpensive. I highly recommend it.

I wrote up an example shell script to show how to use it, which I call [po.sh](https://github.com/tjluoma/po.sh) (for `p`ush`o`ver obviously).

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be exactly what I was looking for.